# MongoDB C Driver

Tags: linux, mongodb, gcc

I compiled the MongoDB C Drivers successfully and run the test scripts also but I am not able to compile the scripts which I am writing myself.

Following is the command and its error output.

```
$ gcc -Isrc --std=c99 ./src/*.c -I ./src/ tutorial.c -o tutorial -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L

./src/env_win32.c:27:53: fatal error: ws2tcpip.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I found that there is no file name `ws2tcpip.h` in `/usr/include` directory

Comment: Strange, your tag says that you are on Linux, but the `C` source with the error is named `env_win32.c`.  Could the mongoDB tutorial code be confused over which OS you are running on?

Comment: What version of the mongoDB C driver are you using?

Comment: Please supply the full path of the directory with the source code you are trying to compile. Most likely, you're trying to compile code that is intended for Win32 use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the `./src/*.c`, that tells gcc to compile all of the c programs in the /src directory which includes some windows only programs.

What worked for me was to tell gcc to include the `libmongoc.so` that was built when the drivers were built.

The following command worked for me.  My drivers are in directory "mongo-c-driver".

```
gcc --std=c99 -I mongo-c-driver/src -o tutorial tutorial.c mongo-c-driver/libmongoc.so
```

In my opinion the mongodb C API documentation is a little buggy in this area.  Also, the latest header files don't match the source code shown in the tutorial.  For example `mongo-insert` requires 4 parameters in the v0.6 headers, but the tutorial shows only 2 parameters.

In researching this problem and trying to recreate it by installing mongoDB and the C driver myself I have discovered that v0.6 of the driver broke compatibility with previous version of the API by adding support for `write_concern` which adds a 4th parameter to the `mongo_insert` function (which can be set to `null`).  The `example.c` program provided in the `docs/examples` directory does not compile in v0.6.  This bug is documented in patch [CDRIVER-157](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/commit/6166e8a12b4350e7ea10b9adcfb399a7c28fdad4) in github for the [c-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver).